# Numpy TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple, how to change the code?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, computer-vision

```
   def on_pushButtonTwo_clicked(self):
    img = np.asarray(Image.open("testtwo.tif").convert # read image, convert it('L'))                            
    img = 1 * (img < 127)

    areasplit = np.split(img.ravel(), 24) # here we are splitting converted to 1D array
    for i in areasplit:
     area = (i == 0).sum()
     print area

    maxr =  areasplit[argmax(sum(areasplit == 0, axis = 0)), :] # selecting subarrays with min and max white pixel numbers
    minr = areasplit[argmin(sum(areasplit == 0, axis = 0)), :]

    distance = cityblock(maxr, minr) # computing distance between subarrays
     print distance


    Result: type error: areasplit[argmax(sum(areasplit == 0, axis=0)), :]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Is there any way to select subarrays with min and max number of white pixels?
   How to change the code correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`areasplit` is a list of ndarrays, not an ndarray, so it cannot take a second index. This should work:

```
maxr =  areasplit[argmax(sum(areasplit == 0, axis = 0))]
minr = areasplit[argmin(sum(areasplit == 0, axis = 0))]
```

Alternatively, convert your list of ndarrays to a 2D ndarray before those calls:

```
areasplit = numpy.array(areasplit)
```

Comment: Thank you. However all distances are zero. Is there argaverage or argmean function, in other words how to select subarray with mean/median white pixel number?